# Format problem of the write.table in R, utf-8 original encode

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, write.table

There is a problem with the `write.table`. `chr2` is correctly shown in the console but fail in the saved txt file.

```
> chr1 = chr2 = rep(NA, 8)
> for(i in 1:8){
+   chr1[i] = letters[i]
+   chr2[i] = intToUtf8(10240+2^(i-1))
+ } 
> 
> chr1
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
> chr2
[1] "⠁" "⠂" "⠄" "⠈" "⠐" "⠠" "⡀" "⢀"
> 

write.table(cbind(chr1, chr2), file = "chr2.txt")
```

[image: chr.txt]

May I know how to get the txt file printing exactly the same way as the console? Thank you!

My OS and R version:

```
version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2020                        
month          10                          
day            10                          
svn rev        79318                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out
```

---------------- June-06 Update ----------------

In fact, what I really want to do is to save a "txt picture" like:

⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣆⢀⠹⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟⢻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟⠉⠻⣿⣦⢀⠘⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡏⢸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇⢸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣦⡀⠈⠻⣧⢀⠘⢿⡟⢠⣤⣌⡇⢀⣴⣅⣤⣄⠙⡟⢡⣤⣈⡇⢸⠟⢠⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠉⠛⢿⣿⣄⢀⠈⢳⡀⢸⣧⣈⡉⠙⠇⢸⣿⠛⣉⣉⢀⠁⣾⣿⣿⡇⢀⡀⢻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣦⣀⢀⠈⠙⠷⣄⢀⣽⣿⡟⠻⠿⠃⣠⠘⢿⢀⠿⠟⢀⣇⠘⠿⠛⡇⢸⣷⡀⢻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⡿⠛⠻⠿⣿⣦⣄⡀⠈⣿⣿⣿⣿⣶⣶⣾⣿⣷⣾⣷⣶⣾⣶⣿⣷⣶⣾⣷⣾⣿⣷⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⡿⠿⣿⣧⣄⣀⢀⢀⢀⠉⠙⢺⣿⠿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠁⢀⡇⢀⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⡇⢀⣿⡿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠶⠶⠤⣼⣿⢀⣿⡿⠋⠉⠛⡏⠉⣿⡏⠉⡟⠋⠉⠻⡟⠉⠋⠉⠃⢀⠙⡇⢀⣿⠟⠉⠉⠻⠉⠹⣿⠉⢻⡟⠉
⡇⢀⣿⣇⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣿⣿⢀⣿⠁⢠⣶⢀⢰⢀⢹⢀⢸⢀⠐⠓⢀⠁⢀⣰⣶⡇⢀⣶⡇⢀⣿⢀⢰⡆⢀⠃⢀⡇⢀⠈⠇⢀
⡇⢀⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⢀⣿⡀⠘⠿⢀⢸⡆⢀⢀⣿⢀⠰⡶⠶⡆⢀⣿⣿⡇⢀⣿⡇⢀⢿⢀⠸⠇⢀⣼⢀⢀⣸⢀⢀⣸
⣇⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣿⣷⣄⣀⣠⣿⣿⣀⣸⣿⣦⣀⣀⣠⣧⣀⣿⣿⣇⣀⣿⣷⣄⣀⣦⣀⣀⣴⣿⣆⣀⣿⣇⣀⣿

I have uploaded my code and the example picture to GitHub:

https://github.com/CarltonChen/TxtDotPic

Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, coercing the two vectors to a data.frame to write it as a table already converts the characters to unicode references. You can see that when you use `data.frame(chr1,chr2)`.

I frankly do not know how to write unicode symbols to tables, but if you are able to compose lines of a file (concatenate the values with `'\t'`), you can write them using `writeLines()` to a file with native encoding:

```
f = file("specialchar.txt",open="w",encoding="native.enc")
writeLines(paste(chr1,chr2,sep='\t'),con=f, useBytes=T)
close(f)
```

When I do this, I get the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I updated my question and maybe it makes some sense to you.

Comment: If it does not have to be a table, `writeLines()` with correct encoding should work even better. You just compile the lines as vectors, collapse them to character and write them as a line.

Comment: Thank you! With your help, the problem is solved